# proving that $r(X \cup Y) = r(X \cup cl(Y)).$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics, graphic-matroids

Here is the question I am trying to prove:

Let $M$ be a matroid, and $r$ and $cl$ be its rank function and its closure operator. Prove the following:

$(d)$ $r(X \cup Y) = r(X \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X) \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X \cup Y))$

**Here is my attempt:**

First, proving that $r(X \cup Y) = r(X \cup cl(Y)).$

Since $X \subseteq X$ and $Y \subseteq cl(Y),$ then $X \cup Y \subseteq X \cup cl(Y) $ and hence by the properties of the rank function we have $r(X \cup Y) \leq r(X \cup cl(Y)) $. Now, for proving the other direction I do not know how to get that $cl(Y) \subseteq Y.$ I know that $X \subseteq X$ and $r(Y) = r(cl(Y))$ but I do not know how to complete. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You posted this question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776812/proving-that-rclx-cup-cly-rclx-cup-y

Comment: @Math1000 No the required is different I think.

Comment: You certainly shouldnt be using $cl(Y) \subseteq Y $ in your proof considering thats not true unless the set is closed. Also pay more attention to your poset in question: $r(X \cup Y ) \subseteq r(X \cup cl(Y))$ should have a $\leq$

Comment: Yeah @cdsb I see your point .... it is a number not a set

Comment: @cdsb So how can I prove without using that $cl(Y) \subseteq Y$? the problem does not say anything about the closure of $Y$

Answer (score 1):

We have that the rank of a subset $Z$ of $M$ is the smallest cardinality of a subset $K$ of $M$ such that $Z\subset cl(K)$. It follows that for any subsets $Z$, $T$ of $M$ we have $r(Z)\le r(T)$ provided $Z\subset T$. Since the closure operator on $M$ is monotone and idempotent, if $Z\subset cl(K)$ then $cl(Z)\subset cl(cl(K))=cl(K)$, thus $r(Z)=r(cl(Z))$. The monotonicity of rank implies the following lemma.

**Lemma.** We have $r(Z)=r(T)=r(cl(Z))$ for any sets $T$, $Z\subset T\subset cl(T)$. $\square$

We have $X\subset cl(X)$, $Y\subset cl(Y)$. On the other hand, since $X\subset X\cup Y$ and $Y\subset X\cup Y$, we have $cl(X)\subset cl(X\cup Y)$ and $cl(Y)\subset cl(X\cup Y)$. Thus $$X\cup Y\subset X\cup cl(Y)\subset cl(X)\cup cl(Y)\subset cl(X\cup Y).$$ Lemma applied to $Z=X\cap Y$ and $T=X\cup cl(Y)$ or $T=cl(X)\cup cl(Y)$ implies that $$r(X\cup Y)=r(X\cup cl(Y))=r(cl(X)\cup cl(Y))=r(cl(X\cup Y)).$$

Comment: I think in the fourth line, in the last equality, you meant $r(cl(Z)) = r(cl(K))$ or I am missing something

Comment: I do not agree with your last statement how is being subsets leads to the rank function is equal?

Comment: @Emptymind We have $r(Z)=r(cl(Z))$, because $cl(Z)$ is contained in $cl(K)$ too, so the rank of $cl(Z)$ is not bigger than the rank of $Z$. Also I clarified the arguments a bit and stressed the key argument as lemma.