# Proving that $r(cl(X) \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X \cup Y))$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics, graphic-matroids

Here is the question I am trying to prove:

Let $M$ be a matroid, and $r$ and $cl$ be its rank function and its closure operator. Prove the following:

$(d)$ $r(X \cup Y) = r(X \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X) \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X \cup Y))$

**Here is my attempt:**

Third, proving that $r(cl(X) \cup cl(Y)) = r(cl(X \cup Y)).$

I know that $cl(X) \subseteq cl(X \cup Y)$ and $cl(Y) \subseteq cl(X \cup Y),$ then $cl(X) \cup cl(Y) \subseteq cl( X \cup Y) $ and hence by the properties of the rank function we have $r(cl(X) \cup cl(Y)) \leq r(cl(X \cup Y)) $. Now, for proving the other direction I know that $cl(X \cup Y) \subseteq cl(cl(X) \cup cl(_Y)).$ But then I know that $r(X) = r(cl(X))$ but I do not know how to complete. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Continuing what you've written:
$$
r(cl(X\cup Y)) \leqslant r(cl(cl(X)\cup cl(Y))) = r(cl(X)\cup cl(Y)).
$$

Comment: @Math1000  ...... I can not see your point ............ How did you know this? do you have a rigor proof for this?

Comment: @Math1000 why is the closure distributed over the union?

Comment: I agree with the last equality in your line @Math1000

Comment: @Math1000 I got your point thank you very much :)!